# What does "Non-zero wait status: 9" mean when running test using Devel::Cover?

Tags: perl, unit-testing

When I am running only the tests, all of them passes, but when I am running using `HARNESS_PERL_SWITCHES=-MDevel::Cover` in order to generate the coverage, after a few tests I get this exit status `9`. What does it mean?

Comment: I suspect it means the process was killed by signal 9, the KILL signal.